# In TeamCity, is there a system/environment variable for the current build configuration id?

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity, if you know the build configuration id, then you can generate URLs like this:

```
http://example.org/guestAuth/repository/download/bt222/.lastSuccessful/exampleBuild.zip
```

But see that "bt222"? That's the Build Configuration ID; it is generated by TC when you set up the build configuration, and it's static. The [Atlassian docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Configuration#BuildConfiguration-BuildConfigurationID) seem to say that the way to determine it is to look at your URL, on screen.

Thing is, I need to get at it programmatically, in the msbuild script, so that the same build script can serve multiple build configurations. TC otherwise has [so many nice handy variables](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Predefined+Build+Parameters) that I'm just hoping I've missed it somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it as parameter to your build script and set it in build configuration settings from outside.

Build script should not depend on the build server, it should work locally as well.

Comment: Nice work-around. Since the command line parameters are part of the build configuration itself, it's clean to just add  /property:BuildConfigurationID=bt222. In each configuration, I'd just have to enter this separately. That'll work fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9):

The configuration ID is available as `%system.teamcity.buildType.id%.`

Verified to work in Teamcity 7.1.5

Comment: And now in TeamCity 9.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit shaky to rely on these ids, maybe you can approach it from another angle, and use Dependent builds and artefacts? Have you looked into that? We use that a lot to communicate files from one build configuration to another.

Comment: Oh, yes, we do a ton of that. But I don't see how that helps me generate a URL to various build artifacts, useable by users (or in my case, an auto-update mechanism inside the app, which is looking for release notes of any newly available version). Thanks for the your time, though, I appreciate it.